# How do I update Parity's enode id?

Tags: parity, enode

I am running `Parity` in a Virtual Machine. I have copied VM and trying to run both `Parity's` parallel in both Virtual Machines. Since their `enode` is same on both VMs, I cannot run both `Parity` in parallel. I guess their connection into same node collide.

**[Q]** I want to update on going Parity's enode. How could I do that, do I need to clean all Parity's memory?

Is there any way to run Parity nodes having same enode-id in parallel?

Please note that: I observe that Parity nodes having same enode-id connected with different account cannot connect into same Ethereum enode node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing or removing the network key changes the enode address:

```
~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/network/key
```

You could increment the value by one or generate a new one or remove it and parity will take care of that.

Comment: Is there a way to manually change the key in order to generate a specific enode ID?  I accidentally deleted the network key and need to restore my enode ID.

Comment: I think that's what the `--identity` flag does, try to play around with this. But you can also set the network key value to anything you like.

Comment: I will look at --identity but are you suggesting that the network key is the same as the enode ID?  Because I do not think that is correct.  (I think the enode ID is maybe the *public* key?)

Comment: Exactly, the enode is somehow public, while the network key is private.

Comment: How could I do same approach for `geth` node? Please see: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/43356/4575 @Rando

Comment: The Parity enode is derived from the private network key file. If you know the private key beforehand you can generate the enode. See https://hodovi.ch/posts/assigning_the_etherium_enode/