# How could I update my enodeID using `geth`?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have an Ethereum node on a Amazon AWS instance. When I clone my node, it will generate with the same `enode-ID`. When both machine try to connect to peers, they get race each other, so one of them able to connect to peers but other cannot.

**[Q]** How could I change my `enodeID` on using `geth`?

[Solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18317/4575) for `Parity` node:

> Changing or removing the network key changes the enode address:
>
> `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/network/key` You could increment the
>   value by one or generate a new one or remove it and parity will take
>   care of that.

I don't know how to do this approach on `geth`.

Comment: As long as they're both running on a different IP address / port their enode IDs will be unique - or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: They are not. First nodeA initialized the genesis block and sync the blockchain. later when I clone that nodeA into nodeB, nodeB has the same `enodeID`. @TC8

Comment: here's an example enode ID: `enode://6f8a80d14311c39f35f516fa664deaaaa13e85b2f7493f37f6144d86991ec012937307647bd3b9a82abe2974e1407241d54947bbb39763a4cac9f77166ad92a0@10.3.58.6:30303?discport=30301` i.e. a hexadecimal ID followed by an IP address and port number. If you run two nodes you'll need them on distinct IP/port combinations or they won't work properly. By changing the port number of one of them you won't change the hexadecimal part of the enode string but you will change the port numbers at the end, which should be all you need to avoid conflict

Comment: You didn't understand my question I guess. Both have different IP and Port, but both has same initialization. When I clone a node , its node's enode-ID is not updated. @TC8

Comment: I understood the question but my idea for the solution must be wrong so please feel free to ignore me :)

Comment: No worries. Solution is to remove network key but I don't know how on geth. @TC8

Comment: geth has a `--nodekey` flag to provide a file, or `--nodekeyhex` to provide a hex string directly if that helps! [This might also help?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/how-to-produce-enode-from-node-key/28978#28978)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Geth's key file is:
`~/.ethereum/geth/nodekey`
for Linux
`Library/Ethereum/geth/nodekey` for Mac

More details can be found in geth source code [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/589b603a9b1e17930d1e83ca64ce7cdc4c3d5c85/node/config.go#L39) for the definition:

`datadirPrivateKey      = "nodekey"            // Path within the datadir to the node's private key`

And [this line](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/589b603a9b1e17930d1e83ca64ce7cdc4c3d5c85/node/config.go#L312) for path resolution.

Comment: Should I delete `~/.ethereum/geth/nodekey` ? @Linmao Song

Comment: Yes, if you delete it and restart geth, it will generate a new one

Comment: On the latest `geth` version nodekey file is located in `/private/geth`